# Cooking up morphisms out of perfect complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I encountered the following situation. I consider the derived category of the category of abelian groups $D(Ab)$, and we fix a non-commutative ring $R$. Now I have a triangulated functor from the derived category of left $R$-modules $D(R)$ into $D(Ab)$. Let's call it $F\colon D(R)\to D(Ab)$.

I am now able to compute that $F(R)\cong M$, some right $R$-module, viewed as a complex concentrated in degree zero. I am wondering how much information this gives me about the functor $F$ itself. To be precise, I would like to restrict $F$ to the category of bounded perfect complexes $D_{perf}^{b}(R)$. Is it now possible to cook up from the isomorphism $F(R)\cong M$ a functorial isomorphism $F(N^{\bullet})\cong N^{\bullet}\otimes_{R}^{L}M$ for every $N^{\bullet}\in D_{perf}^{b}(R)$?

Comment: You can try to compute your functor on any perfect complex by induction on length using the truncation exact triangles.